# Load a different js file with every load of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

so basically I have a JS file, containing objects(var), and I want to be able to load a different Object every time I load the page. So for example, when the page is loaded, a new Objects 'temp' is created, that contains the data of some of the objects data* (data1, data2 etc.) from the JS file. I don't know how that works, and I don't know if I'm gonna need 5 .js files or one with 5 data variables.

```
    var data = {

    'coords' : [[784, 42], [802, 324], [128, 365], [710, 166], [513, 283], [610 , 391], [544, 48], [323, 204], [316, 50], [938, 52]],
    'walkthrough' : [8, 6, 0, 9, 3, 1, 5, 4, 2, 7],
    'highscore' : 2217  
}

var data1 = {
    'coords' : [[784, 42], [933, 211], [304, 190], [756, 264], [365, 395], [129, 302], [504, 261], [650, 393], [283, 26], [593, 35]],
    'walkthrough' : [8, 9, 0, 1, 3, 7, 6, 4, 5, 2],
    'highscore' : 2123

}

var data2 = {
    'coords' : [[784, 42], [591, 289], [242, 289], [710, 150], [465, 371], [589, 146], [667, 24], [323, 204], [173, 173], [898, 197] ],
    'walkthrough' : [8, 2, 7, 4, 1, 5, 3, 9, 0, 6],
    'highscore' : 1897

}

var data3 = {
    'coords' : [[785, 264], [591, 289], [392, 49], [419, 332], [862, 159], [533, 166], [710, 119], [323, 204], [600, 32], [834, 54]],
    'walkthrough' : [2, 7, 3, 1, 0, 4, 9, 6, 8, 5],
    'highscore' : 1573

}

var data4 = {
    'coords' : [[903, 292], [634, 352], [44, 350], [150, 188], [883, 131], [475, 240], [697, 152], [274, 341], [491, 69], [784, 34]],
    'walkthrough' : [2, 7, 5, 1, 0, 4, 9, 6, 8, 3],
    'highscore' : 2167

}
```

What I want is to have an object 'temp', that will have the data from some of the data objects.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible for you to put all the objects in an array? If yes, do a Math.random and let it pick an index!

Comment: I've put an answer below (it's actually pretty much what @A1rPun said - sorry, didn't see that!)  Is the data static, or is it coming from somewhere?  There may be a whole better approach to this.

Comment: For storing such small data 5 js files are not needed.Store it in one file and then randomly choose to select a variable using Math.random() function.

Comment: "need 5 .js files or one with 5 data variables?" - it depends on what "load a different Object every time" actually means. If different file is for different user then store data separately to save traffic (each user will download only what's required for him). On the contrary if every user will eventially need to download all the data (e.g. after going through your website), then store it in one file and prevent users to have to download all the files separately.

Comment: It's static data, and it's not that much content actually, so a few kB, downloaded from every user shouldn't be a problem. Thanks for the suggestions. The solution from Archer is perfectly fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you need...

```
var data = [{
    'coords' : [[784, 42], [802, 324], [128, 365], [710, 166], [513, 283], [610 , 391], [544, 48], [323, 204], [316, 50], [938, 52]],
    'walkthrough' : [8, 6, 0, 9, 3, 1, 5, 4, 2, 7],
    'highscore' : 2217  
}, {
    'coords' : [[784, 42], [933, 211], [304, 190], [756, 264], [365, 395], [129, 302], [504, 261], [650, 393], [283, 26], [593, 35]],
    'walkthrough' : [8, 9, 0, 1, 3, 7, 6, 4, 5, 2],
    'highscore' : 2123

}, {
    'coords' : [[784, 42], [591, 289], [242, 289], [710, 150], [465, 371], [589, 146], [667, 24], [323, 204], [173, 173], [898, 197] ],
    'walkthrough' : [8, 2, 7, 4, 1, 5, 3, 9, 0, 6],
    'highscore' : 1897

}, {
    'coords' : [[785, 264], [591, 289], [392, 49], [419, 332], [862, 159], [533, 166], [710, 119], [323, 204], [600, 32], [834, 54]],
    'walkthrough' : [2, 7, 3, 1, 0, 4, 9, 6, 8, 5],
    'highscore' : 1573

}, {
    'coords' : [[903, 292], [634, 352], [44, 350], [150, 188], [883, 131], [475, 240], [697, 152], [274, 341], [491, 69], [784, 34]],
    'walkthrough' : [2, 7, 5, 1, 0, 4, 9, 6, 8, 3],
    'highscore' : 2167
}];

var thisData = data[Math.floor(data.length * Math.random())];
```

Store all the data in one array, and then just select one of them randomly.  It's a much better approach than having multiple js files as you'll only have one file to maintain.

Comment: Lol @A1rPun.  Very meme.  So lulz.

Comment: @GameAlchemist I agree there's better ways to do this.  I've asked the OP in the question comments what's going on with the data.  I don't like the idea of having such an amount of data in a js file unless it's the only way.  It must be coming from somewhere.

Comment: Sure. JSON files on server + XMLHTTPRequest on client to read them seems really fit for this case.

Comment: JSON was unfortunately unfit, at a certain point and I eliminated it as a possibility some time ago... I can't no longer remember why.... But Archer's solution certainly fits well.